# Wait until element is present

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I searched through every thread on stackoverflow but couldn't find a suitable solution regarding my issue. In 7/10 cases my scripts are falling because they are not finding one specific element. Therefore i'm searching for an oppurtunity to tell my script "wait so long until this element is present and then click on it".

my code looks like:

```
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class LogIn < Test::Unit::TestCase

def setup
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
@base_url = "url"
@accept_next_alert = true
@driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
@verification_errors = []
end
def teardown
@driver.quit
assert_equal [], @verification_errors
end
def test_sms_newsletter
#login
@driver.get "https://secure.shore.com/merchant/sign_in"
@driver.find_element(:id, "merchant_account_email").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "merchant_account_email").send_keys "key"
@driver.find_element(:id, "merchant_account_password").clear
@driver.find_element(:id, "merchant_account_password").send_keys 
"password"
@driver.find_element(:name, "button").click
@driver.get "https://secure.shore.com"
verify { assert_equal "Shore - Manage your customers", @driver.title }
sleep 5
@driver.find_element(:css, "#asMain > header > a.as-Button.is-
active.as-Button--inverted").click
```

The element i'm taking about is the last one:

```
@driver.find_element(:css, "#asMain > header > a.as-Button.is-active.as-Button--inverted").click
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Please update what are you exactly tying to do through `@driver.find_element(:css, "#asMain > header > a.as-Button.is-active.as-Button--inverted").click` on the url  `https://secure.shore.com`. Thanks

Comment: Proper indentation is a huge debugging help

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB. My scripts having troubles to find this element in time because the frontend is not written in a good way. Therefore i want to force the script to find the element first and then continue.

Comment: You are not only finding, you are clicking too. For the element to receive the `click()` you need a proper `css` or `xpath`. Through your `css` I didn't find any element on `https://secure.shore.com`. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a Selenium/Ruby bot to wait before performing an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761677/how-to-get-a-selenium-ruby-bot-to-wait-before-performing-an-action)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet to wait for an element is present. You could put a block like this in front of every element before you use it. If the block times out, the test fails.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser.get "http://localhost/page3"

wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)

# Add text to a text box
input = wait.until {
    element = browser.find_element(:css, "#asMain > header > a.as-Button.is-active.as-Button--inverted")
    element if element.displayed?
}
input.send_keys("Information")
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, i tried your sugesstion but i didn't work out though. I receive an error message:

`Error: test_sms_newsletter(LogIn): NameError: undefined local variable or method wait for #<LogIn:0x0000000138d7d0>`

Answer (score 0):

The wait should work for you. Try to use FluentWait.

If still the problem exists then use JavascriptExecutor . It will operate directly through JS. It should work if the locator is fine. I am giving an example to click any element using JavascriptExecutor

```
elementfield = browser.find_element(:css, "#asMain > header > a.as-Button.is-active.as-Button--inverted")
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', elementfield)
```

Hope it will help you :)