# Ruby - Selenium Webdriver - no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had written a selenium webdriver code in ruby for testing the Razorpay payment page. It works until clicking the button. After that a modal window opens up in AJAX call.

The code i written is below.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome

driver.get 'https://rzp.io/l/kawOIqx'
driver.find_element(:name,"email").send_keys 'tester@gmail.com'
driver.find_element(:name,"phone").send_keys '7584363853'
driver.find_element(:class,"btn").click

sleep 2

if !driver.find_elements(:class,"new-method").empty?
    driver.find_elements(:class,"new-method").click
elsif !driver.find_elements(:class,"payment-option").empty?
    driver.find_elements(:class,"payment-option").first.click
else
    puts 'I am out'
end

sleep 0.5
driver.find_element(:id,"card_number").send_keys '4111111111111111'
sleep 0.5
driver.find_element(:name,"card[expiry]").send_keys '11/21'
sleep 0.5
```

It prints **'I am out'** as i had written and throws **'no such element: Unable to locate element:'** error.

How can i find the element in that AJAX modal and click it? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reach out this page `https://sample_razorpay_payment_page_link` to verify, can you please give the correct url?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Yes. Here it is. https://rzp.io/l/kawOIqx Also updated it in the code above.

Comment: I have to leave now from here. I will write an answer for you. Are you trying to click Card? In which there are four options are appearing, Card,Netbandking,Wallet,UPI/QR?

Comment: @Rajagopalan Yes. I have to click the Card option and use **send_keys** from there. Problem is i can't click Card.

Comment: You need to wait until `new-method` element shows up, notice that you are only giving it `2 seconds` then you check if the element exists

Comment: @MobrineHayde Now i have given it 10 seconds. Still it says **no such element: Unable to locate element:** error and it prints "I am out" as written in program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Selçuk Ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7819964/sel%C3%A7uk-ayhan) for your timely help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213383/2338769

I had to switch to iFrames first and do the **if..else** condition in the code.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(:class, "razorpay-checkout-frame"))

if...
elsif..
end.
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, sorry for being late. Hope you have gotten the answer. My suggestion is to use WATIR which is a wrapper around ruby selenium binding. Switching the frame is pretty easy there and also there are numerous feature which would not be available if you use selenium binding directly.

Comment: Thanks @Rajagopalan. Yeah WATIR seems interesting. Will check out.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an id on that modal frame please update the id in following code and paste it before your `if-else if-else` block :

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(:xpath, "//iframe[contains(@id, 'modal')]"))
```

Comment: Thanks Selçuk Ayhan. Since there is no ID, i used :class instead of xPath for iframes and it works now. :)

Comment: Having a doubt though! Is the above correct way to write code? I am using **sleep 0.5** for each action. Is it necessary?

Comment: using sleeps are the worst practices, you should create your conditional wait methods like wait until element is visible. please cheeck the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507975/wait-until-element-is-present