# Load all elements on page Selenium + Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium

**Notice** I know this has been asked before, I have been attempting to solve this by researching other posts and selenium doc, but I can't resolve the issue.

**Questions:** How can I make all of the elements on page load before selenium starts? Why is my code returning text values on certain webpages and not this one?

**Reproduce the problem** 
I am using Selenium with Ruby & Chrome. The result I am looking for is, going to a website, selecting some text, and its tag name, ie, "//h1 'Diamond Physicians revolutionary healthcare'" and then having selenium check it is there. I have been successful with other webpages, except this site..."https://diamondphysicians.com/" ... I believe it is bootstrap "business" theme so certain elements load once you scroll to them.

This is the best sum of what I have been reading and attempting. (Explicit wait, implicit wait, clicking an element, and I have tried scrolling to the bottom)... [How to get a Selenium/Ruby bot to wait before performing an action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761677/how-to-get-a-selenium-ruby-bot-to-wait-before-performing-an-action)

**code**
*Certain things are hashed out for testing

```
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    #options.add_argument('--headless')
    #options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1280')
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
    #driver.navigate.to "https://diamondphysicians.com/"
    #wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 15)
    driver.get("https://diamondphysicians.com/")
    #element = wait.until {driver.find_element(:class => "widget-title")}
    #element.click
    #driver.element(:class, "widget-title").when_present.click
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")

    substring = "Welcome to the future of primary care!"
    driver.find_elements(:xpath => "//p").each do |r|
        puts "Cell Value: " + r.text
        if r.text.include? substring
            puts "FOUND IT FOUND IT FOUND IT FOUND IT FOUND IT FOUND IT FOUND IT"
        end 
    end
```

When I run this, I get 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: 
Cell Value: Sign up to Diamond Physicians Newsletters to learn the latest new functionalities and exchange experiences with other Diamond Physicians, members or employers

**EDIT**
For anyone who comes across this and needs a good resource, check out this blog. Valid as of 2/2019
https://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/

Comment: Explicit Wait is what you want

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg How would i incorporate this to my code? I want selenium to find the element by tagName (p, h1) and find the one that includes the text i provide. It doesn't return one element. wait.until {driver.find_elements(:xpath => "//h4").each do ... fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath => "//p").each do |r|
        puts "Cell Value: " + r.text
```

Please try this

```
driver.find_elements(:xpath => "//p").each do |r|
        puts "Cell Value: " + driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", r)
```

Please let me know if this work for you.

Comment: This works!!! Can you explain why grabbing this with JS worked vs the other method?

Comment: Because when element text unable to fetch by Normal method that means it is hidden.then you have to use JS to get the value.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even think about that. Makes perfect sense.